# Making your classes work with floats as well as with integers (analyzing a piece of code)

Tags: c++

I'm analyzing a piece of code and I came across this

```
class X 
{ 
//content
}; 

typedef X<float> X;
```

Can someone points me to something closer to the source of what this (using 
`<type>` to basically make a second class working with second type) is called, how does it work or in what cases we use this so I can continue the search. (In my case it was used as a class defining a 3-dimensional vector.)

this is the entire code:

```
template<typename T> 
class Vec3 
{ 
public: 
    T x, y, z; 
    Vec3() : x(T(0)), y(T(0)), z(T(0)) {} 
    Vec3(T xx) : x(xx), y(xx), z(xx) {} 
    Vec3(T xx, T yy, T zz) : x(xx), y(yy), z(zz) {} 
    Vec3& normalize() 
    { 
        T nor2 = length2(); 
        if (nor2 > 0) { 
            T invNor = 1 / sqrt(nor2); 
            x *= invNor, y *= invNor, z *= invNor; 
        } 
        return *this; 
    } 
    Vec3<T> operator * (const T &f) const { return Vec3<T>(x * f, y * f, z * f); } 
    Vec3<T> operator * (const Vec3<T> &v) const { return Vec3<T>(x * v.x, y * v.y, z * v.z); } 
    T dot(const Vec3<T> &v) const { return x * v.x + y * v.y + z * v.z; } 
    Vec3<T> operator - (const Vec3<T> &v) const { return Vec3<T>(x - v.x, y - v.y, z - v.z); } 
    Vec3<T> operator + (const Vec3<T> &v) const { return Vec3<T>(x + v.x, y + v.y, z + v.z); } 
    Vec3<T>& operator += (const Vec3<T> &v) { x += v.x, y += v.y, z += v.z; return *this; } 
    Vec3<T>& operator *= (const Vec3<T> &v) { x *= v.x, y *= v.y, z *= v.z; return *this; } 
    Vec3<T> operator - () const { return Vec3<T>(-x, -y, -z); } 
    T length2() const { return x * x + y * y + z * z; } 
    T length() const { return sqrt(length2()); } 
    friend std::ostream & operator << (std::ostream &os, const Vec3<T> &v) 
    { 
        os << "[" << v.x << " " << v.y << " " << v.z << "]"; 
        return os; 
    } 
}; 

typedef Vec3<float> Vec3f;
```

Comment: Are you thinking of *templates*?

Comment: This wouldn't compile. Both because `X` is not a template, and due to a conflicting declaration of `X`.

Answer (score 3):

You have probably missed some related piece of code appearing before `class X`:

```
template <typename T> // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
class X 
{ 
//content
};
```

> Can someone points me to something closer to the source of what this is called,

That's called a *class template*.

> how does it work

The code provided in the class template definition will be instantiated for various types as provided by

```
typedef X<float> X;
```

or

```
typedef X<int> Y;
```

Comment: What bugs me is the <> part of class template... how does writing class for an int, for example 3d vector class, work automatically for float when you write
     typedef X<float>
And sorry for the format of the question I'm very very new to stackoverflow :(